# Dynamic Routes, Redirects, and VueJS Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm building an app using Vue.js and Vue Router. The routes I have set up are Home (/) and a dynamic user route (/user/:id) where the user information is passed into the page as an object of data.

I have two questions about this:

1) If I go directly to app.com/user/1, nothing happens - I get a blank page. In my router file, I have a redirect to '/', but that doesn't seem to catch what I'm aiming for (redirecting any direct navigation from a user to the home page).

**router/index.js**

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: Url.pathPrefix,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/user/:id',
            name: 'user-detail',
            component: UserDetail,
            props: true
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            redirect: '/'
        }
    ],
    scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
})
```

How do I redirect my users to Home?

2) If I go to home, and then click to go to /user/1, the page loads correctly. If I click the Back button in the browser, Home loads correctly. But if I click the Forward button, the /user/1 page hangs again - blank page.

Should I apply the same solution to Question 1 here as well and redirect them to Home? Or is there a better method to handle this situation?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify you don't want any one to be able to directly navigate to the user page without first being on the home page?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I would just use a [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) similar to the doc's [example](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html) with the meta field.